# The import javazoom cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

hi all
i use the javazoom.jl.player.Player package but it is says  The import javazoom cannot be resolved. i am using eclipse and doing Android project. i clean the project still the same error is shown. please correct me.

Comment: Compiler error (red lines in the editor)? Runtime error (on the device/emulator)?

Comment: it is Compiler error(red lines in editor)

Comment: it is compiler error(red lines in the editor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If eclipse can't resolve a package fragment of an import statement, then it tells you (with that error), that there is no library on the **classpath** that contains a class from that package (or from a package whose name starts with the missing part).

An easy way for standard java/eclipse:

1. create a folder `lib` in your projects root directory (with the eclipse workbench!)
2. copy and paste the jar into that folder
3. right-click the copied jar and select "add to build path".

This should eliminate the compiler errors immediately.

---

(Previous part of the answer)

Taking the error message literally, it looks like you have a line of code like that:

```
import javazoom;
```

This would be wrong, because we don't import *packages* but *classes from a package*. To import all classes from the `javazoom` package, we'd say:

```
import javazoom.*;
```

Comment: i am using like this import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
if use import javazoom.*; the same error is repeated.

Comment: Understand - so you have a red line under the word `javazoom` in the import statement.

Comment: i did the following but i have the same error (compile error).
my project structure is: my project name is Bpm. i created a folder called lib under Bpm. and paste the jlayer1.0.1.zip in the folder.
and right click the zip build path->add to build path. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the .jar of jLayer ( http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html )

And add into classpath in the way Andreas_D told you.

Comment: i did the following but i have the same error (compile error). my project structure is: my project name is Bpm. i created a folder called lib under Bpm. and paste the jlayer1.0.1.zip in the folder. and right click the zip build path->add to build path. please guide me

Comment: Open this zip, and get the jLayer.jar from there, this is the file you should add to classpath.