# I'm having trouble importing javazoom library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm trying to make a small rhythm game with the javazoom library. I downloaded JLayer1.0.1 and added jl1.0.1.jar to my project (in eclipse) under Modulepath (I tried putting it under classpath and neither worked).

When I do:

```
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
```

I get an error message saying "The type javazoom.jl.player.Player is not accessible".

I tried importing it both externally and by creating a folder called lib in my project and adding it from there but neither worked. What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I go into Player.class under jl1.0.1.jar it says: "source not found; the JAR file jl1.0.1.jar has no source attachment". Is this relevant?

--edit
Ok so I'm guessing that the javazoom library is outdated and is no longer supported properly in the latest Java JRE System library. What I tried was I went to configure build path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Execution environment -> select JavaSE 1.7 -> Finish -> Apply and close, the error disappeared. However, I had to comment out module-info.java (I'm guessing that we don't need this in JavaSE 1.7?) The error's gone but I'm still curious. Anybody know a valid reasoning for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676617/the-import-javazoom-cannot-be-resolved ?

Comment: I read that post but still not working :(